# Curl not working fine with sending file and data at the same time

Tags: php

this is the code that I have used to upload a zip file and other data to another page.There is a problem that if I try to send file and post data at the same time ,the other page will not get post data and If I remove the line which send file ,other form data would be posted .
Here is the code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$post_array = array(

    "upload" => "Upload",'s_id' => stripcslashes($s_id),
    'u' => 'persian',
     "my_file" => '@'.dirname(__file__)."/downloads/1393-11-14_1_7.zip"
    );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_array);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

The zip file and url is correct and there is no error from curl.Also the $url is correct and I get response from that page.
What's wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't `__file__` be `__FILE__`?

Comment: @Barmar Tried that but no different.

Comment: I find out the problem.The problem is with sending big files.I'm trying to send 400MB file and it does not work and If I try to send smaller size there is no problem.How should I solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size